# Safe strcpy implementation with C++

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, c++14

After reading [this](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/) article, I've decided to take a crack at implementing a "safe_strcpy" function that would remove some of the errors that the author speaks about. Obviously, my `safe_strcpy()` function is inspired by his. Below, I've created a simple class that houses a `std::array` of one of the many different kinds of strings. My `safe_strcpy()` functions rely on always null-terminating the array given.

I have a few worries about my implementation:

1. The lines with `out[N - 1] = static_cast<T>(0)` seem wrong when the underlying character type is `wchar_t`. In this sense, I want the array to terminate with something to the effect of `L"0"`. Will this work? If not, how can I fix it?
2. Should I be concerned with any performance issues or any "gotchas" that I didn't think of?
3. Is this a viable solution to the `safe_strcpy` conundrum? In other words, would *you* use this class in production code? What kind of improvements or extensions should this class use?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template <size_t N, class T = char>
struct char_array
{
    typedef T                value_type;
    typedef const T          const_value_type;
    typedef T&               reference;
    typedef const T&         const_reference;
    typedef std::array<T, N> container;

    typedef typename container::size_type       size_type;
    typedef typename container::iterator        iterator;
    typedef typename container::const_iterator  const_iterator;

    typedef typename container::reverse_iterator        reverse_iterator;
    typedef typename container::const_reverse_iterator  const_reverse_iterator;

    /* Constructor */
    char_array()
    {
        static_assert((is_same<unsigned char, T>::value || is_same<char, T>::value ||
                      is_same<wchar_t, T>::value || is_same<signed char, T>::value ||
                      is_same<char16_t, T>::value || is_same<char32_t, T>::value)  &&
                      N > 0,
                      "char_array initialized with invalid type or size");
    }

    /* Destructor */
    ~char_array() {}

    /* Copy constructor and assignment */
    char_array(const char_array<N,T> &other) = default;
    char_array& operator=(const char_array<N,T> &other) = default;

    /* Move constructor and assignment */
    char_array(char_array<N,T> &&other) { buf_ = std::move(other.buf_); }
    char_array& operator=(char_array<N,T> &&other) 
    { 
        buf_ = std::move(other.buf_);
        return *this;
    } 

    /* Delegate members of internal container */

    iterator         begin() { return buf_.begin(); }
    const_iterator   begin() const { return buf_.begin(); }

    iterator         end() { return buf_.end(); }
    const_iterator   end() const { return buf_.end(); }

    const_iterator   cbegin() const { return buf_.cbegin(); }    
    const_iterator   cend() const { return buf_.cend(); }

    reverse_iterator         rbegin() { return buf_.rbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator   rbegin() const { return buf_.rbegin(); }

    reverse_iterator         rend() { return buf_.rend(); }
    const_reverse_iterator   rend() const { return buf_.rend(); }

    const_reverse_iterator   crbegin() const { return buf_.crbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator   crend() const { return buf_.crend(); }

    reference       operator[](size_type i) { return buf_[i]; }
    const_reference operator[](size_type i) const { return buf_[i]; }

    size_type        size() const { return buf_.size(); }
    size_type        max_size() const { return buf_.max_size(); }
    bool             empty() const { return buf_.empty(); }

    reference        at(size_type n) { return buf_.at(n); }
    const_reference  at(size_type n) const { return buf_.at(n); }

    reference        front(size_type n) { return buf_.front(n); }
    const_reference  front(size_type n) const { return buf_.front(n); }

    reference        back(size_type n) { return buf_.back(n); }
    const_reference  back(size_type n) const { return buf_.back(n); }

    value_type*       data() { return buf_.data(); }
    const value_type* data() const { return buf_.data(); }

    void fill(const value_type &val) { buf_.fill(val); }
    void swap(char_array &x) { buf_.swap(x.buf_); }

private:
    container buf_;
};

/*
    Allow "template magic" to automatically deduce
    the size of the given array. NOTE: this only works with
    statically-allocated arrays (e.g. arrays with a size known
    at compile time)
    @param[in] - out - a reference to the array
    @param[in] - src - the source string

    Usage:
    char buf[10];
    safe_strcpy(buf, "This is a string > 10 chars");
 */
template <class T, size_t N>
void safe_strcpy(T (&out)[N], const T *src)
{
    static_assert((is_same<wchar_t, T>::value || is_same<signed char, T>::value ||
                is_same<unsigned char, T>::value || is_same<char, T>::value || 
                is_same<char16_t, T>::value || is_same<char32_t, T>::value)  &&
                N > 0, "Incompatible type for safe_strcpy");
    memcpy(out, src, N * sizeof(T));
    out[N - 1] = static_cast<T>(0);
}

template <class T, size_t N, class S>
void safe_strcpy(char_array<N,T> &out, const S *src)
{
    static_assert(is_same<T, S>::value, "Source content type different from char_array destination");
    memcpy(out.data(), src, N * sizeof(T));
    out[N - 1] = static_cast<T>(0);
}

template <class Os, size_t N, class T>
Os& operator<<(Os &os, const char_array<N,T> &arr)
{
    for (const auto &c : arr) os << c;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t buf[10];
    safe_strcpy(buf, L"really long string that's greater than 10 freaking characters!!!!");
    wcout << buf << "\n";

    char_array<10> buffer;
    safe_strcpy(buffer, "This is a string longer than 10 chars");
    cout << "Max size is: " << buffer.max_size() << "\n";
    cout << buffer << "\n";
}
```

Comment: _"... with something to the effect of `L"0"`"_ You probably meant `L"\0"`.

Comment: For #1, you can simply make a traits class and specialize for `wchar`. For example: `null_terminator<T>::value` is either `"\0"` or `L"\0"` depending on whether T is `char` or `wchar`, respectively.

Comment: That's an amazingly over-engineered solution `;)`. I think something in the lines of `safe_strcpy(char * dest, size_t destMax, const char * src, size_t scrLen)` is already a big improvement, without 100 lines of template boilerplate involved. But then again, strcopying in C++ is pretty rare. `std::string` covers 99% of the cases for you already!

Comment: BTW, please don't `use namespace` in a header file! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 12):

**Break out your type trait**

You have this large amount of `is_same` checks in a couple places. Break it out in its own trait, and call it something like `is_char`:

```
template <class T> is_char : std::false_type { };
template <> is_char<wchar_t> : std::true_type { };
template <> is_char<char> : std::true_type { };
template <> is_char<signed char> : std::true_type { };
...
```

What way, in your `char_array`, you can just have:

```
static_assert(is_char<T>::value, "invalid type, expected a char");
static_assert(N > 0, "invalid size, expected N > 0");
```

Furthermore, those asserts don't need to be in the constructor, they can be in the body of the class.

**Lots of code Repetition**

Pretty much all of your `char_array` code is just duplicating what `std::array` does. What does `char_array` actually give you? It costs you aggregate-initialization, and that's not nothing. Ultimateyl, it's really just a `std::array<>` with some extra conditions on `T` and `N`.

But we can just use those same conditions to SFINAE the `safe_strcpy`:

```
template <class T, size_t N, class S,
          class = std::enable_if_t<is_char<T>::value &&
                                   (N > 0) &&
                                   is_same<T, S>::value>>
void safe_strcpy(std::array<T,N> &out, const S *src)
{
    memcpy(out.data(), src, N * sizeof(T));
    out[N - 1] = 0;
}
```

And now we have no need for `char_array` at all.

---

If you really want to keep the type, I'd just inherit:

```
template <size_t N, class T=char>
struct char_array : std::array<T, N>
{
    static_assert(is_char<T>::value, "invalid type, expected a char");
    static_assert(N > 0, "invalid size, expected N > 0");
};
```

**memcpy to `std::copy`**

Instead of copying raw bytes, and having to remember to multiply, you can just use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) - which will under-the-hood do the same thing anyway, but will be less error-prone. So instead of:

```
memcpy(out.data(), src, N * sizeof(T));
```

Write:

```
std::copy(src, src+N, out.data());
```

Comment: These points are good, but unfortunately your versions of the code still all overrun the source.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's already covered in a different review.

Answer (score 10):

- **Gotcha**

  There is a potential for illegal access. While the code guarantees that the destination buffer is not overflown, it will however access *beyond the source* buffer if it is smaller than the destination. `memcpy` is just a wrong tool here.
- **Will I use it?**

  Given a very limited use case of this approach (static buffers only) and a template size specialization (a serious potential for code bloat) I will probably stay with the good old `strncpy`. Rumors of its un-safety are highly exaggerated.

Comment: You're right about your first point. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: strncpy is absolutely disastrously unsafe. The design is just horrible. When an overflow happens, you are left with something that isn't a C string.

Answer (score 3):

One hard cold truth is that C-Strings cannot be fixed: not knowing the size of the buffer (either inbound or outbound) is a recipe for failure, and the band-aids (`strncpy`, `strlcpy`, ...) are just attempting to patch the symptoms.

Another hard cold truth is that `wchar_t` is broken by design as it is non-portable (16 bits on Windows and 32 bits on Unix). Therefore you should not use it at all and instead rely on explicitly sized types `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

---

Your own code is subject to run-time issues as a result:

- you never guarantee that `src` is not null, at the very least an `assert` would be useful and the documentation should reflect it, some compilers also have specific annotations (gcc's `__attribute__((nonnull(2)))` for example)
- you never check that `src` is long enough and blindly copy `N` bytes, even though in general there is no guarantee that the source is longer than the destination

And has a number of design limitations:

- you do not allow copying piecemeal (useful to concatenate...)
- you only allow copying into statically allocated buffer
- you treat the strings as a meaningless sequence of bytes, and truncate without regard for its encoding (but then, `std::string` does so too...)

---

If you cannot afford `std::string`, or wish to design an alternative where buffer ownership can be external (so as to use fixed-sized buffer), then I advise using a class approach and simply make it compatible with C-Strings for interoperability:

- by allowing construction from a C-String
- by keeping it NUL-terminated for cheap conversion into a C-String

And then, this class can easily implement safe copy!

**Last note: `std::string` may not be as costly as you think it is, if you are avoiding it for performance reason, measure first...**

A rough example (untested!) of a safer alternative to C-String:

```
//
//  Fixed-Capacity String
//
//  It never allocates or re-allocates, but instead uses the
//  externally provided buffer.
//
template <typename T>
class fcstring {
public:
    //  Construction
    explicit fcstring(T* cstring):
        _capacity(cstring ? std::strlen(cstring) : 0),
        _size(_capacity),
        _buffer(cstring)
    {}

    template <size_t N>
    explicit fcstring(T (&str)[N]):
        _capacity(N-1),
        _size(N-1),
        _buffer(str)
    {}

    //  "buffer" is assumed to already point at a valid C-String
    //  of size "size" (not counting the terminating NUL-byte).
    //  "capacity" may be additionally provided if the buffer is known
    //  to be larger than "size", it then represents the number of "T"
    //  than the "buffer" may contain, not counting the NUL-byte.
    fcstring(T* buffer, size_t size, size_t capacity = 0):
        _capacity(capacity ? capacity : size),
        _size(size),
        _buffer(buffer)
    {}

    //  Copy
    void assign(fcstring const& other) {
        size_t const copied = std::min(_capacity, other._size);
        std::memcpy(_buffer, other._buffer, copied);
        _buffer[copied] = T();
        _size = copied;
    }

    //  Conversion to C-String
    //  /!\ Be mindful that any embedded NUL character will
    //  /!\ result in a truncated output
    T const* c_str() const { return _size ? _buffer : ""; }

private:
    size_t _capacity;
    size_t _size;
    T* _buffer;
}; // class fcstring
```